# Remove some text from a string after some constant value(string)

Tags: string, c#-4.0

```
 Input: String str="Fund testing testing";
 Output: str="Fund";
```

After fund whatever the text is there need to remove that text.
Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is a `.Substring()` method, as you can provide it the start index of your original string and length of the string you need:

```
var length = "Fund".Length;
var str = "Fund testing testing";
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, length)); //returns "Fund"
var str1 = "testFund testing testing";
Console.WriteLine(str1.Substring(4, length)); //returns "Fund"
var str2 = "testFund testing testing";
Console.WriteLine(str2.Substring(str2.IndexOf("Fund"), length)); //returns "Fund"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regular expression like this:

```
string strRegex = @".*?(Fund).*";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = @"Fund testing testing";
string strReplace = @"$1";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

As mentioned in comments below, replace can lack performance and is kind of overkill, so regex Match can be better. Here is how it looks like:

```
string strRegex = @".*?(Fund).*";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = "\n\n" + @"   Fund testing testing";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
        var fund = myMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(fund);
    }
}
```

Note that Groups first element is your entire match

Comment: Why use Replace, if you can use `Match`?

Comment: @VMAtm because you are replacing, and not matching :-)

Comment: This will not work if `Fund` not at the start of the string, should add the start symbol to the regex

Comment: @Jcl Why replacing the (may be) big amount of the chars if all you need to do is return matched string?

Comment: @VMAtm you're right, matching is better in scope of perfomance. But then, why author doesn't simply make an assignment of "Fund" string? I think he needs an example on replacing substrings in string.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy I think the `Fund` is just an example, and is not known on compile time.

Comment: @VMAtm Also edited my answer so that regex can cut off all characters before Fund